# Google MAPS API - Trying to have a map on two separate HTML pages but on one of them an error occurs

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

"Map: Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed null."

-The height of the div is set in the css.

Javascript (googleMaps.js):

```
    function initMap() {
    try {
   

      const sportHall2 = { lat: 51.18310959584043, lng: 
         4.38829092697164 }; 
     
        const map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-2"), 
        {
          zoom: 13,
          center: sportHall2,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          zoomControl: true,
          fullscreenControl: true,
          streetViewControl: true,
        });
    
        const map2b = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-2b"), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: sportHall2,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          zoomControl: true,
          fullscreenControl: true,
          streetViewControl: true,
        });
        } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } 
    }
```

HTML Page 1:

```
 <script src="/scripts/googleMaps.js"></script>
          <div class="grid-card">
                <h3>Pius X-instituut</h3>
                <h5>Bekijk de sporthal hier.</h5>
                <p>Adres: Hof Van Tichelen 28 2020 Antwerpen</p>
                <div id="map-2"></div>
            </div>
    <script src="/scripts/googleMaps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
    key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=
    initMap&libraries=&v= 
    weekly" async></script>
```

HTML Page 2 (error occurs and map won't display on this page):

```
  <script src="/scripts/googleMaps.js"></script>

        <div class="grid-card map-2b-container">
            <h3>Pius X-instituut</h3>
            <h5>Bekijk de sporthal hier.</h5>
            <p>Adres: Hof Van Tichelen 28 2020 Antwerpen</p>
            <div id="map-2b"></div>
        </div>

    <script src="/scripts/googleMaps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
    key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=
    initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" async></script>
```

CSS:

```
#map-2{
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
}
 
#map-2b{
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
}
```

ERROR:
Se {message: "Map: Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed
null.", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Se ([https://maps.googleapis.com/m…](https://maps.googleapis.com/m%E2%80%A6)
6ho4&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly:156:128"}

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I'm using JavaScript. @geocodezip thank you for the advice, I believe it should be a reprex/mcve/mwe now.

Comment: I would expect you to get that error on both pages (each page tries to access both divs, but each page only has one of them...).  Perhaps only access the div if it exists; or use the same name for the map div on both pages.

Comment: That makes sense, I tried same name for the map div it made no difference. I also tried to check if div exists before running the function that also didn't work. After that I tried to have both map div elements on both HTML pages, and on HTML Page 1 still only map-2 showed up, where as on HTML Page 2 neither map loaded.  The error stayed the same.

Comment: I'm not allowed to post questions anymore after this question, this was a genuine question I don't understand.

Comment: Thanks to @geocodezip - I was able to make it work, I used both the same name for each div on each separate page, and also checked if the div exists before executing the Map() constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Source: [Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple#maps_map_simple-javascript)

```
const mapDiv = document.getElementById("map-2b");

const map2b = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: sportHall2,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    fullscreenControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried embedding google maps using iframe? If not then this is the easiest way to have map in the HTML.

Step1: go to https://www.google.com/maps
Step2: enter the location you want to embed.
Step3: Click menu -> share or embed map -> embed map tab
Step4: Copy the iframe tag and paste it in the HTML file

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, however it's difficult to get the responsiveness to work as I want it to with the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
   function initMap() {
   try {
   

   const sportHall2 = { lat: 51.18310959584043, lng: 
     4.38829092697164 }; 

   if(document.getElementById('map-2')){
    const map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-2"), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: sportHall2,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        fullscreenControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
    });
  }
}
```

Code above works by setting both div Id's on each separate page "map-2" and checking if the div exists before running the Map() constructor.